# Grails Test Bundle Error

Tags: grails

While running `grails test-app -integration` I get these errors:

```
2013-08-05 10:57:34,701 [WARN ] 
(main)grails.app.resourceMappers.org.grails.plugin.resource.BundleResourceMapper - 
Cannot create a bundle from resource [/less/dummy.css], 
the content type [application/octet-stream] is not supported. Set the resource to exclude bundle mapper.
```

(This is printed for all css/js/less... resources)

What does that mean. How do I resolve this?

---

This is my mime types setting:

```
grails.mime.types = [
    all:           '*/*',
    atom:          'application/atom+xml',
    css:           'text/css',
    less:          'text/less',
    csv:           'text/csv',
    form:          'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    html:          ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
    js:            'text/javascript',
    coffee:        'text/coffeescript',
    json:          ['application/json', 'text/json'],
    multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data',
    rss:           'application/rss+xml',
    text:          'text/plain',
    xml:           ['text/xml', 'application/xml']
]

// What URL patterns should be processed by the resources plugin
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*']
```

Comment: do you have any non-standard mime types that have not been defined in your config.groovy (grails.mime.types)?

Comment: @dunnless I've updated my post to show the config. I've added less and coffeescript, but is makes no difference in the warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging it appears to be a problem with `MockServletContext` in Spring Framework, which has been addressed in version 3.2.2 ([JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10334))

Grails 2.2.4 is still on Spring Framework 3.1.x, and I'm not sure if Grails 2.3 is already upgraded to the 3.2.x version.

So basically it's an annoying but harmless issue that will disappear in future Grails releases.